# Link to view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I simply want a link within an 'Index' view to open the corresponding 'project' view.

routes.rb

```
get '/project', to: 'projects#new'
get '/projects', to: 'projects#index'
get'/project/:id', to: 'projects#show'
post '/projects/new', to: 'projects#create'

#----Resources----
resources :users
resources :projects
resources :hazards
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<td class="ellipsis">
 <%= link_to project.name, project_path(:id) %> 
</td>
```

So all of the other views are working and I can manually type the project/id and see the view. When I try the link however instead of generating the url project/id it generates project.id and points to the projects#create path.

I know the answer to this will be simple, but I'm blowed if I can figure it out. An explanation will be great, so I can understand my mistake.

Comment: Assuming you have a valid `project`, try `link_to project.name, project`. I'll add explanation, should that work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and get right back...

Comment: @jvillian Sorry man that doesn't change anything still generates the url project.9 rather than project/9 when it generates the bad url it lso still renders my #create path/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the other answers seem good. I would also offer that you should define your routes using standard `resources` approach:

```
resources :projects
```

Which will give you:

```
     projects GET    /projects(.:format)              projects#index
              POST   /projects(.:format)              projects#create
  new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)          projects#new
 edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)     projects#edit
      project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)          projects#show
              PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)          projects#update
              PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)          projects#update
              DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)          projects#destroy
```

You can prune those using `only:` or `except:` as needed/appropriate.

Then you should be able to do:

```
link_to project.name project
```

You'll often see this as any one of the following:

```
link_to project.name project_path(id: project.id)
link_to project.name project_path(project.id)
link_to project.name project_path(project)
link_to project.name project
```

All of which are equivalent.

Oh, yes, and as Sebastian Palma notes, you're currently passing a symbol for `id` here:

```
link_to project.name, project_path(:id)
```

In which case, rails thinks the symbol `:id` is an `id`, which naturally it is not.

BTW, these declarations:

```
get  '/project',      to: 'projects#new'
get  '/projects',     to: 'projects#index'
get  '/project/:id',  to: 'projects#show'
post '/projects/new', to: 'projects#create'
```

Include some *non conventional* items. Specifically, the first, third, and fourth entries.

In general, when using resourceful routes, you want the object name (i.e., `project`) to be in the plural form, (i.e., `projects`). If you wanted to handcraft these, I believe they would look more like:

```
get  '/projects',       to: 'projects#index'
get  '/projects/new',   to: 'projects#new',    as: :new_project
get  '/projects/:id',   to: 'projects#show',   as: :project
post '/projects',       to: 'projects#create'
```

Which would then mimic a subset of the routes generated by `resources :projects`:

```
   projects GET    /projects(.:format)            projects#index
new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)        projects#new
    project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)        projects#show
            POST   /projects(.:format)            projects#create
```

You should handcraft your routes ***or*** use `resources :projects`. You should not do both (as it appears you may be doing).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Let me work through it make sure I understand it and make the changes. Ill let you know asp how it works out. Thanks again.

Comment: YES...Success... Thanks a bunch dude, I appreciate your help, I've been bouncing around the answer on and off for days. I'll try and digest what you've said and make sure I understand it, but at least I can now move on. Marked as correct and up voted... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Modify routes for show as follows:

```
get '/projects/:id', to: 'projects#show'
```

but instead of above I will suggest you to, use resource full routes

ie. `resources :projects`

Comment: Hey Ganesh I tried your solution and received the following error: Invalid route name, already in use: 'project' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Comment: you may defined routes two times. please check and remove duplicate routes.